# EntitySet 'Department' is based on type 'Admin' that has no keys defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

When I am accessing my Model's Data from a Controller. I got this error **EntitySet 'Department' is based on type 'Admin' that has no keys defined**. I am using MVC5 with visual stdio 2013 RC.

deptID (Primary key), deptName, Description : all are column name of Department table.

desgID (Primary key), desgName, description: all are column name of Designation table.

Objective :- I want to create a dialog box of deptName or desgName on the view page but now I want to resolve these issue.

I am referring these link :-
[EntityType 'Category' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862013/entitytype-category-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entitytype)

[ASP.NET MVC 3 EntityType has no key defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344244/asp-net-mvc-3-entitytype-has-no-key-defined)

but according these link. I am trying to use [Key] with my primary key column but it's not prompt in mvc5.

Model :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace mvcAppraisalSystem.Models
{
  public class Admin
 {
    public int deptID { get; set; }
    public string deptName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int desgID { get; set; }
    public string desgName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

 public class AdminDBContext : DbContext
 {
    public DbSet<Admin> Department { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Admin> Designation { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Entity Framework can only determine which property you wish to have as the key if the key is named simply `Id` or includes the class name, i.e. `AdminId`.  It has no way of knowing that `deptID` should be the key field for an `Admin` Class.  To fix this, there is an annotation `[Key]` that can be attached to a property.  To use this annotation, you need to reference Entity Framework in your project and have a using statement `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

Comment: God bless you, dear friend!