# Entity framework Database first Integration tests

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, testing, sql-server-ce, integration-testing

I have been wrapping my head around UnitOfWork and Repository patterns lately. I have finally come up with a solution that works for my case, great. Now I wanted to add some tests into my application to make sure my repositories are performing as expected. After reading and rereading multiple articles on the subject, I have come to the conclusion that I would like to use, at least to start with, SQL Server CE to fake the database for my tests so I can test Linq-to-Entities queries.

I have set up the app.config for my test project as such:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
                    </parameters>
            </defaultConnectionFactory>
            <providers>
                <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
                    type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
```

However, when I try to create the database in my test setup, I get an exception:

```
Proj1.Test.Persistence.Product: : EntityType 'Product' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

And I assume that this is because there are no Attributes on the models, saying which value is the key, because I am using the Database first approach.

I have read several SO questions related to this, but none seem to fit my problem. So my question is, is it possible to configure SQL CE to create a database for tests, even though my Model is database first?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862013/entitytype-category-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entitytype  OR this link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344244/asp-net-mvc-3-entitytype-has-no-key-defined

Comment: The models are being generated from the database so I can't add the [Key] attribute to the model.